# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'duration'

Tags: python, moviepy

I am trying to edit my video using moviepy. And when I want to cut a part of it I get error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'duration'`
Why ?

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip0 = VideoFileClip('08.mkv')
clip0 = clip0.set_audio(f'../Rus_sound/08.mkv'[:-3] + 'mp3')
end = 0
start = 0
lista = [0.4,0.6]
movie1 = '08.mkv'
movie2 = '../Bubble_Background_Video3.mp4'
clip0 = VideoFileClip(movie1)
audio = f'../Rus_sound/{movie1}'[:-3] + 'mp3'
clip1 = clip0.set_audio(audio)
    
w = clip1.w
h = clip1.h
fps = clip1.fps
clip2 = VideoFileClip(movie2).resize(height=h, width=w).set_fps(fps)
durata = clip1.duration - end
lista = [start] + [i*durata for i in lista ] + [durata]
    
stocked = []
for i in range(1, len(lista)):
    o = i-1
    clip = clip1.subclip(lista[o], lista[i])
    stocked.append(clip)
    if i != len(lista)-1:
        stocked.append(clip2)
clip = concatenate_videoclips(stocked, method='compose')
```

This is my Error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-42faa818ba3e> in <module>
----> 1 clip = clip1.subclip(0, 449.241)

<decorator-gen-152> in subclip(self, t_start, t_end)

~/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py in wrapper(f, *a, **kw)
     87         new_kw = {k: fun(v) if k in varnames else v
     88                  for (k,v) in kw.items()}
---> 89         return f(*new_a, **new_kw)
     90     return decorator.decorator(wrapper)
     91 

<decorator-gen-151> in subclip(self, t_start, t_end)

~/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py in apply_to_mask(f, clip, *a, **k)
     27         the clip created with f """
     28 
---> 29     newclip = f(clip, *a, **k)
     30     if getattr(newclip, 'mask', None):
     31         newclip.mask = f(newclip.mask, *a, **k)

<decorator-gen-150> in subclip(self, t_start, t_end)

~/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py in apply_to_audio(f, clip, *a, **k)
     41     newclip = f(clip, *a, **k)
     42     if getattr(newclip, 'audio', None):
---> 43         newclip.audio = f(newclip.audio, *a, **k)
     44     return newclip
     45 

~/Anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moviepy/Clip.py in subclip(self, t_start, t_end)
    382             t_start = self.duration + t_start   # Remember t_start is negative
    383 
--> 384         if (self.duration is not None) and (t_start > self.duration):
    385             raise ValueError("t_start (%.02f) " % t_start +
    386                              "should be smaller than the clip's " +

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'duration'
```

Comment: The code in the error message is different from the code you have shown above. Please update either the error message or the code to match the other.

Answer (score 2):

The PROBLEM here, which would have been clear if you read the documentation, is that the `set_audio` function does not take a string.  It takes an `AudioFileClip` object.  `moviepy` is smart enough not to do the actual work at that point; it just remembers what you wanted for audio.  Later, when you try to use that clip, it tries to look up the audio file's duration, and it finds a string where it expected an object.

```
clip1 = clip0.set_audio(AudioFileClip(audio))
```